# Need to replace img src with a template code

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace all the /media/* url's in several database entries with 
{{media url=URL}}

I have the following as a test.:

```
<img src="/media/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
<img src="/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
<img src="/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
<img src="/media/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
```

I was trying to use the following Regex

```
<img.+?src=\"\/media(.+?)[\"'].*?>/g
```

End result should be something like:

```
<img src="{{media url="/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg}}" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
```

I'm planning on using php's preg_replace

What should I use for the regex to find and replace the url?  I was trying to figure it out here: https://regex101.com/r/kF3gI1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and assumed all entries are going to be using double quotes to encase the image URL. Here's the code I used to test:

```
$tests = array(
    '<img src="/media/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />',
    '<img src="/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />',
    '<img src="/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />',
    '<img src="/media/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />',
);

foreach ($tests as $str) {
    echo preg_replace("/<img.+?src=\"(.+?)\"/","<img src=\"{{media url=\"$1\"}}\"",$str)."\r\n";
}
```

And here are the results:

```
<img src="{{media url="/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg"}}" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
<img src="/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
<img src="/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
<img src="{{media url="/wysiwyg/nutritionfacts/NLAHCLEA00600000CP.jpg"}}" alt="NLA for Her Her Cleanse 60ct" />
```

Comment: That's not going to work.  I only want the /media/ folder the other 2 urls were "test cases".

Comment: preg_replace("/<img.+?src=\"\/media(.+?)\"/","<img src=\"{{media url=\"$1\"}}\"",$str)  seems to work.  Revise your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I tired to fix your answer to make it correct, but my edit was denied.  Remove: $str = str_replace("<img src=\"/media", "<img src=\"", $str); and update the results and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! I went to bed shortly after posting so I didn't see this until now. I think the answer is correct now.